# Как расставить объекты в canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Хочу доделать свой диалоговый квест. Карта там генерируеться пока случайным образом. Что изменить в коде, чтоб можно было карту редактировать вручную, на JavaScript'е. (расстановка квадратов с задаными координатами) Вот код который отвечает за случайную генерацию:

```
//генерация ландшафта
function createWorld()
{
   console.log('Creating world...');

  //создание пустоши
  for (var x=0; x < worldWidth; x++)
  {
    world[x] = [];

    for (var y=0; y < worldHeight; y++)
    {
      world[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }

// раставляем скалы случайным образом
  for (var x=1; x < worldWidth; x++)
  {
    for (var y=1; y < worldHeight; y++)
    {
          if (Math.random() > 0.75)
          world[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }
```

Кто в теме помогите пожалуйста или скиньте ссылку где про это почитать

Comment: `if (Math.random() > 0.75) world[x][y] = 0;` зачем? `world[x][y]` уже везде нуль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте ф-цию `createObj(ctx, x, y, w, h)`, где
`ctx` - контекст канваса
`x, y` - координаты объекта
`w, h` - его размеры

А внутри такое

```
function createObj(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h); // нарисует прямоугольник в нужными параметрами
}
```

и потом используйте так
`createObj(ctx, 0, 0, 10, 10)` - нарисует на канвасе объект

Можете создавать теперь таких кучу

```
createObj(ctx, 100, 65, 100, 30);
createObj(ctx, 25, 17, 45, 25);
createObj(ctx, 87, 4, 5, 47);
createObj(ctx, 47, 8, 74, 2);
```

Но это убьет автоматизацию и через цикл уже будет сложнее вывести все скалы или другие объекты, если только не создать массив/объект c расположением, допустим

```
var scalaMap = [
    {x : 0, y : 11, w : 10, h : 45},
    {x : 25, y : 11, w : 4, h : 81},
    {x : 36, y : 74, w : 64, h : 28},
];

for(var i = 0; i < scalaMap.length; i++) {
    var data = scalaMap[i];
    createObj(ctx, data.x, data.y, data.w, data.h);
    /* 
       так же можете добавить в хранилище объектов
       или что-нибудь еще с ними сделать
    */
}
```

Теперь, что бы добавить еще одну скалу, нужно добавить в `scalaMap` объект с данными

Comment: существует уже масса готовых библиотек, в которых уже все готово. Так что идею реализовать, при использовании оных, будет не сложно.

Comment: @ThisMan  посмотрите пожалуйста дополнил свой коментарий, может ещё, что подскажите

Comment: @ThisMan Спасибо дельный совет , буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Почти весь код есть уже. Сейчас мир создается случайным образом. Весь канвас это пространство по которому можно ходить , дальше случ образом скалы(преграды)
Проблема в том , чтоб скриптом задать координаты скал (никакого сложного редактора карт) просто задать положение скал(пространства по которому перс неможет ходить) 
я думал достаточно будет отредактировать эту часть кода :

```
   for (var x=1; x < worldWidth; x++)
     {
       for (var y=1; y < worldHeight; y++)
       {
          if (Math.random() > 0.75)
          world[x][y] = 0;
       }
     }
```

и вместо `Math.random` задать координаты